# Display a single value in Google chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I'm working on a dashboard, and i'm using Google Chart which is great.. but now i want to display just one data field, so no graph, its just poor text/number i want to get displayed. Is this possible while still using Google chart setup?

Like Google analytic does --> [Google Analytic](http://screencast.com/t/JGlCvdNBMM)

EDIT: 
I found the needed code, its was just `.getValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)`

Comment: Why do you even need Google chart tools to do that?

Comment: I'm loading all the dashboard data in with a #wrapper, so i just wanted to display one of these data fields. So eg. if my dataset looks like `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Link', 'Clicks'],
          ['Clicktype 1', 6800],
          ['Clicktype 2', 5400],
          ['Clicktype 3', 4800],
          ['Clicktype 4', 3000],
          ['Clicktype 5', 3800],
          ['Clicktype 6', 2800],
          ['Clicktype 7', 1600],
          ['Clicktype 8', 1000],
          ['Clicktype 9', 200],
        ]);`